# Emploi de 'tschüss'

Tags: oral, salutations, allemand

Selon [Le Figaro](https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/2018/07/31/37002-20180731ARTFIG00017-d-o-vient-le-mot-tchuss.php#:%7E:text=C%27est%20pour%20dire%20%C2%ABau,et%20le%20%C2%ABbye%C2%BB%20anglais.) le mot allemand tschüss peut s'utiliser pour dire « au revoir » et prendre congé. Il a été intégré oralement dans la langue française, au même titre que le « ciao » italien et le « bye » anglais.

> « Tchuss, reviens vite », « Bon voyage, profite bien, tchuss ! ».

1. L'emploi de Tschüss est-il répandu partout en France ?
2. Quelle écriture est préférable en français : tschüss ou tschuss ?
3. Quelle est la prononciation correcte en français : /t͡ʃʏs/ ou /t͡ʃus/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Non. Je ne l'ai entendu dire que de personnes qui connaissaient au moins un peu l'allemand.
2. Les deux sont possibles, le *ü* n'étant pas nécessaire ici en français.
3. Il n'y a pas de raison de le prononcer autrement que /t͡ʃys/, à moins de n'avoir appris ce mot qu'en le lisant écrit sans tréma.

Comment: Prima. Danke schön !

Comment: *– Bitte schön!*

Comment: pour apporter mon expérience personnelle : 1. je connais des gens qui l'utilisent régulièrement et qui n'ont jamais fait d'allemand de leur vie 3. Je n'ai jamais entendu autre chose que /t͡ʃus/ (un bon "tchousse" bien franchouillard, aucune intention d'accent allemand)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Intéressant, merci. C'est donc dans ce cas ce que j'ai mis en 3.

Comment: @jlliagre Tu es sûr ? Le /ʏ/ de /t͡ʃʏs/ est un "u" allemand qui n'existe pas en français, mais qui est proche de /t͡ʃys/ (qui rime avec "russe", mais que je n'ai jamais entendu). /t͡ʃus/ quant à lui rime avec "tousse". Sauf si j'ai mal compris, mon expérience à l'oral ne correspond pas bien à ce que tu as mis en 3.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat J'ai corrigé la transcription API, copier-coller malencontreux, c'est bien un /y/ que je voulais mettre. Il n'est cependant pas très différent du /Y/ allemand. Une oreille française ne distingue pas vraiment les deux. J'ai bien compris que tu l'entends prononcé /t͡ʃus/ et pour moi, ce sont des gens qui lisent "tschuss" et le prononcent comme un mot étranger où le *U* correspond à un "ou", comme l'anglais, l'espagnol, l'allemand ou à peu près n'importe quelle langue. Il n'y a peut-être qu'en français que cette lettre ne se prononce pas /u/.